# Separating the stanzas of a poem with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to separate the stanzas with XSLT.

This is my input and I need to separate this four stanzas also on XSLT (method HTML)

I used

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tei:l">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/> <br/> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

but my stanzas are join

[image: My input]

Comment: It's helpful if you post the XML, not pictures of the XML. Also, what is the desired output?  What are the requirements for grouping? Showing a for loop and a picture of input XML doesn't tell us much about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Define a template rule with `match="tei:lg"` that outputs the required separator between stanzas, and that does `<xsl:apply-templates select="l"/>`; and then a template rule with `match="tei:l"` to process each line.

Answer (score 0):

> but my stanzas are join

Assuming that `lg` represents a stanza, and that you want to separate stanzas by an additional line break, you could do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tei:lg">
    <xsl:for-each select="tei:l">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
        <br/> 
    </xsl:for-each>
    <br/> 
</xsl:for-each>
```